# Format a number as 2.5K if a thousand or more, otherwise 900

Tags: javascript, jquery, formatting, numbers

I need to show a currency value in the format of `1K` of equal to one thousand, or `1.1K`, `1.2K`, `1.9K` etc, if its not an even thousands, otherwise if under a thousand, display normal `500`, `100`, `250` etc, using JavaScript to format the number?

Comment: Do you also need `M` and `G`?

Comment: I will need M yes...Can you help?

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17633462/format-a-javascript-number-with-a-metric-prefix-like-1-5k-1m-1g-etc

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/60988355/80428 for a locale friendly ES2020 solution

Answer (score 288, accepted):

Sounds like this should work for you:

```js
function kFormatter(num) {
    return Math.abs(num) > 999 ? Math.sign(num)*((Math.abs(num)/1000).toFixed(1)) + 'k' : Math.sign(num)*Math.abs(num)
}
    
console.log(kFormatter(1200)); // 1.2k
console.log(kFormatter(-1200)); // -1.2k
console.log(kFormatter(900)); // 900
console.log(kFormatter(-900)); // -900
```

Comment: Minor fix suggested... Should be lowercase k for thousands.  Upper is for Kilos.  Tried to edit, but requires at least 6 characters changed before it will take.

Comment: How do I inset a php variable inside here and use it? i.e. if my number variable is `$mynumber_output` where do I insert this to use it? For example, say `$mynumber_output` = 12846, I would like 12846 converted to `12.8k`

Comment: Note that one kilobyte is 1024 bytes in some cases: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kilobyte

Comment: Any idea how we can make 1000 display as 1.0k instead of 1k?

Comment: Doesn't completely answer the user's question. "I will need M yes...Can you help?" - Carl Weis

Comment: Why is it that when a typical developers writes javascript code they think it is suddenly OK to perform the same calculation more than once (twice, three times...) ?  why is Math.abs(num) called twice ?

Comment: `Math.round(Math.abs(num)/100)/10` instead of `(Math.abs(num)/1000).toFixed(1)` so typescript is happy

Comment: I'm afraid that I'm missing the point, but I think this example has unneeded function calls.
Why not  just return this way? `return Math.abs(num) > 999 ? (num/1000).toFixed(1) + 'k' : num`

Comment: Why `Math.sign(num)*Math.abs(num)` ? Isn't it just `num`?

Comment: Here is simplified version
`const kFormatter = (num) => Math.abs(num) >= 1000 ? +(num/1000).toFixed(1) + 'k' : num;`

Answer (score 432):

A more generalized version:

```js
function nFormatter(num, digits) {
  const lookup = [
    { value: 1, symbol: "" },
    { value: 1e3, symbol: "k" },
    { value: 1e6, symbol: "M" },
    { value: 1e9, symbol: "G" },
    { value: 1e12, symbol: "T" },
    { value: 1e15, symbol: "P" },
    { value: 1e18, symbol: "E" }
  ];
  const regexp = /\.0+$|(?<=\.[0-9]*[1-9])0+$/;
  const item = lookup.findLast(item => num >= item.value);
  return item ? (num / item.value).toFixed(digits).replace(regexp, "").concat(item.symbol) : "0";
}

/*
 * Tests
 */
const tests = [
  { num: 0, digits: 1 },
  { num: 12, digits: 1 },
  { num: 1234, digits: 1 },
  { num: 100000000, digits: 1 },
  { num: 299792458, digits: 1 },
  { num: 759878, digits: 1 },
  { num: 759878, digits: 0 },
  { num: 123, digits: 1 },
  { num: 123.456, digits: 1 },
  { num: 123.456, digits: 2 },
  { num: 123.456, digits: 4 }
];
tests.forEach(test => {
  console.log("nFormatter(%f, %i) = %s", test.num, test.digits, nFormatter(test.num, test.digits));
});
```

The `lookup` contains SI prefix sorted ascending. The `regexp` matches trailing zeros (and the dot, if possible) in the number.

#### Note:

`Array.findLast` requires ES2023. If you get an error, change `lookup.findLast(...)` to `lookup.slice().reverse().find(...)`

Comment: @SalmanA - Great help, it fails if one pass arg as string, if cleansed with parseFloat works well. Thank you!

Comment: Small fix for numbers less < 1000, add {value: 1E0, symbol: ""} to var si =

Comment: @GiovanniAzua just replace `if (num >= si[i].value)` with `if (Math.abs(num) >= si[i].value)`

Comment: what does `.replace(rx, "$1")` do ?

Comment: @M.Octavio the regex is used to trim trailing zeros e.g. `1.0` becomes `1` and `1.10` becomes `1.1`

Comment: To account for negative values use `Math.abs(num) >= si[i].value` in the if statement inside the loop

Comment: also, it might be great to treat the special case at the beginning. if(num === 0) return 0;

Comment: '[0-9]' can be simplified to '\d'

Comment: Great solution, but this doesn't account for negative numbers. Trying to figure out how.

Comment: @rukshan see comments above that mention Math.abs

Comment: UPDATE : I added a simple `if (num<0)` and then added a "-" sign infront of the returned value if it is, to account for negative numbers. Had to use another variable though.

Comment: I think the abbreviation for billion is B - https://abbreviations.yourdictionary.com/different-abbreviations-thousand-million-billion

Comment: @john the original version of answer used SI prefixes (https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metric_prefix). Billion is Giga. Of course you can change it.

Comment: if I give `{ num: 999.9, digits: 0 }` it will return `1000` not `1k`

Comment: accepted answer should be the one using JS native formatter

Answer (score 265):

ES2020 adds support for this in `Intl.NumberFormat` Using notation as follows:

```js
let formatter = Intl.NumberFormat('en', { notation: 'compact' });
// example 1
let million = formatter.format(1e6);
// example 2
let billion = formatter.format(1e9);
// print
console.log(million == '1M', billion == '1B');
```

Note as shown above, that the second example produces `1B` instead of `1G`.
`NumberFormat` specs:

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Intl/NumberFormat/NumberFormat
- https://tc39.es/ecma402#numberformat-objects

Note that at the moment not all browsers support ES2020, so you may need this
Polyfill: https://formatjs.io/docs/polyfills/intl-numberformat

Comment: That package has been deprecated, so please use this link:
https://www.npmjs.com/package/@formatjs/intl-numberformat

Comment: Note: Chrome supports the `notation` and `compactDisplay` but FireFox 77 and Safari 13.1 still do not support it so you'll likely need the polyfill.

Comment: Wow, Firefox *just* added support for this in v. 78, it seems. Of course, 2+ years from now, this comment's going to look stupid. :P (It's funny to me though because the code runs for me but it doesn't convert properly, so I'll need to do an update.)

Comment: There are a couple of issues with compact and its very flexible.

Comment: Eg. For german compact, when you want M for million, it does not give M, but rather a german specific alternative. 
```const number = 12453456.789;

console.log(new Intl.NumberFormat('de-DE', { style: 'currency', currency: 'EUR', notation:'compact' }).format(number));
```
// 12 Mio. €

Comment: Also for Germany and some language's any number in thousand's will not have compact. But it will be displayed as such

Comment: Note the above example formats `12345` as `12K` and not `12.3K`. You can add `maximumSignificantDigits` or `maximumFractionDigits`, depending on the behaviour you want.

eg `Intl.NumberFormat("en", { notation: "compact", maximumSignificantDigits: 3 }).format(12345) === "12.3K"` 

or `Intl.NumberFormat("en", { notation: "compact", maximumFractionDigits: 1 }).format(12345) === "12.3K"`

Answer (score 126):

Here's a simple solution that avoids all the `if` statements (with the power of `Math`).

```
var SI_SYMBOL = ["", "k", "M", "G", "T", "P", "E"];

function abbreviateNumber(number){

    // what tier? (determines SI symbol)
    var tier = Math.log10(Math.abs(number)) / 3 | 0;

    // if zero, we don't need a suffix
    if(tier == 0) return number;

    // get suffix and determine scale
    var suffix = SI_SYMBOL[tier];
    var scale = Math.pow(10, tier * 3);

    // scale the number
    var scaled = number / scale;

    // format number and add suffix
    return scaled.toFixed(1) + suffix;
}
```

#### Bonus Meme

[What does `SI` stand for?](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_System_of_Units)

Comment: I really like your solution. To be able to shorten negative values as well, I multiply the number by -1 before and after determining the tier, since Math.log10(negativeValue) would return NaN.

Comment: Just use `Math.abs` to add support to negative numbers, like that: `var tier = Math.log10(Math.abs(number)) / 3 | 0;`.

Comment: Thanks, I made the change to enable negative numbers.

Comment: Does this work just like the accepted answer without any issues?

Comment: Thanks, that's actually the most understandable answer, in terms of what's happening.

Comment: Yea, this one makes a lot more sense and is much easier to read, especially with the comments. It also works with negative numbers too, which is a plus.

Answer (score 95):

Further improving Salman's Answer because it returns nFormatter(33000) as 33.0K

```
function nFormatter(num) {
     if (num >= 1000000000) {
        return (num / 1000000000).toFixed(1).replace(/\.0$/, '') + 'G';
     }
     if (num >= 1000000) {
        return (num / 1000000).toFixed(1).replace(/\.0$/, '') + 'M';
     }
     if (num >= 1000) {
        return (num / 1000).toFixed(1).replace(/\.0$/, '') + 'K';
     }
     return num;
}
```

now nFormatter(33000) = 33K

Comment: Anyway to do this without rounding the number? 1,590,000 will return 1.6M.

Comment: Sometimes its hard to know when to post a new answer of edit an existing one, something I use to decide is if I steal the code from another users answer, I usually edit their answer so that they can get the recognition instead of me stealing their code.

Comment: @Yash you're the code I'm trying to implement in the counter script but not getting this is my codepen link https://codepen.io/Merajkhan/pen/MMoxGE?editors=1010 Can you help me out how to implement this logic I want K, L, M units have to come.

Answer (score 54):

A straight-forward approach has the best readability, and uses the least memory. No need to over-engineer with the use of regex, map objects, Math objects, for-loops, etc.

### Formatting Cash value with K

```js
const formatCash = n => {
  if (n < 1e3) return n;
  if (n >= 1e3) return +(n / 1e3).toFixed(1) + "K";
};

console.log(formatCash(2500));
```

### Formatting Cash value with K M B T

```js
const formatCash = n => {
  if (n < 1e3) return n;
  if (n >= 1e3 && n < 1e6) return +(n / 1e3).toFixed(1) + "K";
  if (n >= 1e6 && n < 1e9) return +(n / 1e6).toFixed(1) + "M";
  if (n >= 1e9 && n < 1e12) return +(n / 1e9).toFixed(1) + "B";
  if (n >= 1e12) return +(n / 1e12).toFixed(1) + "T";
};

console.log(formatCash(1235000));
```

### Using negative numbers

```
let format;
const number = -1235000;

if (number < 0) {
  format = '-' + formatCash(-1 * number);
} else {
  format = formatCash(number);
}
```

Comment: @Jan - Updated my post with an example, but felt it was simple enough to compute the negative form using `'-'  +  formatCash(-1 * number)`

Answer (score 29):

```
/**
 * Shorten number to thousands, millions, billions, etc.
 * http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metric_prefix
 *
 * @param {number} num Number to shorten.
 * @param {number} [digits=0] The number of digits to appear after the decimal point.
 * @returns {string|number}
 *
 * @example
 * // returns '12.5k'
 * shortenLargeNumber(12543, 1)
 *
 * @example
 * // returns '-13k'
 * shortenLargeNumber(-12567)
 *
 * @example
 * // returns '51M'
 * shortenLargeNumber(51000000)
 *
 * @example
 * // returns 651
 * shortenLargeNumber(651)
 *
 * @example
 * // returns 0.12345
 * shortenLargeNumber(0.12345)
 */
function shortenLargeNumber(num, digits) {
    var units = ['k', 'M', 'G', 'T', 'P', 'E', 'Z', 'Y'],
        decimal;

    for(var i=units.length-1; i>=0; i--) {
        decimal = Math.pow(1000, i+1);

        if(num <= -decimal || num >= decimal) {
            return +(num / decimal).toFixed(digits) + units[i];
        }
    }

    return num;
}
```

Thx @Cos for comment, I removed Math.round10 dependency.

Comment: You can change the if to `Math.abs(num) >= decimal`.

Answer (score 23):

## Give Credit to Waylon Flinn if you like this

This was improved from his more elegant approach to handle negative numbers and ".0" case.

The fewer loops and "if" cases you have, the better IMO.

```
function abbreviateNumber(number) {
    const SI_POSTFIXES = ["", "k", "M", "G", "T", "P", "E"];
    const sign = number < 0 ? '-1' : '';
    const absNumber = Math.abs(number);
    const tier = Math.log10(absNumber) / 3 | 0;
    // if zero, we don't need a prefix
    if(tier == 0) return `${absNumber}`;
    // get postfix and determine scale
    const postfix = SI_POSTFIXES[tier];
    const scale = Math.pow(10, tier * 3);
    // scale the number
    const scaled = absNumber / scale;
    const floored = Math.floor(scaled * 10) / 10;
    // format number and add postfix as suffix
    let str = floored.toFixed(1);
    // remove '.0' case
    str = (/\.0$/.test(str)) ? str.substr(0, str.length - 2) : str;
    return `${sign}${str}${postfix}`;
}
```

jsFiddle with test cases -> https://jsfiddle.net/qhbrz04o/9/

Comment: There's still an annoying bug: `abbreviateNumber(999999) == '1000k'` instead of `'1M'`. This is because `toFixed()` also rounds the numbers. Not sure how to fix it, though :/

Comment: @VitorBaptista If `toFixed()` rounds the number anyway, you might as well round the number before sending it to `abbreviateNumber()`, so it returns `1M` instead of `1000k`. Not a solution, but a workaround.

Comment: If you don't want rounding you can do this after the scale step: `const floored = Math.floor(scaled * 10) / 10;`

Comment: doesn't work properly with negative numbers

Comment: @forsureitsme sorry i haven't seen this for a year... i added your change. wrx!

Answer (score 16):

this is is quite elegant.

```
function formatToUnits(number, precision) {
  const abbrev = ['', 'k', 'm', 'b', 't'];
  const unrangifiedOrder = Math.floor(Math.log10(Math.abs(number)) / 3)
  const order = Math.max(0, Math.min(unrangifiedOrder, abbrev.length -1 ))
  const suffix = abbrev[order];

  return (number / Math.pow(10, order * 3)).toFixed(precision) + suffix;
}

formatToUnits(12345, 2)
==> "12.35k"
formatToUnits(0, 3)
==> "0.000"
```

Answer (score 16):

I think it can be one solution.

```js
var unitlist = ["","K","M","G"];
function formatnumber(number){
   let sign = Math.sign(number);
   let unit = 0;
   
   while(Math.abs(number) >= 1000)
   {
     unit = unit + 1; 
     number = Math.floor(Math.abs(number) / 100)/10;
   }
   console.log(sign*Math.abs(number) + unitlist[unit]);
}
formatnumber(999);
formatnumber(1234);
formatnumber(12345);
formatnumber(123456);
formatnumber(1234567);
formatnumber(12345678);
formatnumber(1000);
formatnumber(-999);
formatnumber(-1234);
formatnumber(-12345);
formatnumber(-123456);
formatnumber(-1234567);
formatnumber(-12345678);
```

Comment: Thanks,
This is helpful Because this is not a round return figure like others.

Comment: This function use a lot of resources because it's iterating over the same number again and again. My web app was freezing in Chrome and Safari and was because I was using this function several times 

Comment: I think that's not with this function.
I tested it with 100000 calls and nothing happened.
Please share your code.

Comment: For the number "1000" this returns "1000". To return "1K" replace the "> 1000" with ">= 1000" in the while line

Answer (score 14):

The simplest and easiest way of doing this is

```
new Intl.NumberFormat('en-IN', { 
    notation: "compact",
    compactDisplay: "short",
    style: 'currency',
    currency: 'INR'
}).format(1000).replace("T", "K")
```

This works for any number. Including `L` `Cr` etc.

**NOTE: Not working in safari.**

Comment: not working at all on node.js afaict

Answer (score 11):

You can use the [d3-format](https://www.npmjs.com/package/d3-format) package modeled after Python Advanced String Formatting [PEP3101](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3101/) :

```
var f = require('d3-format')
console.log(f.format('.2s')(2500)) // displays "2.5k"
```

Answer (score 11):

#### Short and generic method

You can make the `COUNT_FORMATS` config object as long or short as you want, depending on the range of values you testing.

```js
// Configuration    
const COUNT_FORMATS =
[
  { // 0 - 999
    letter: '',
    limit: 1e3
  },
  { // 1,000 - 999,999
    letter: 'K',
    limit: 1e6
  },
  { // 1,000,000 - 999,999,999
    letter: 'M',
    limit: 1e9
  },
  { // 1,000,000,000 - 999,999,999,999
    letter: 'B',
    limit: 1e12
  },
  { // 1,000,000,000,000 - 999,999,999,999,999
    letter: 'T',
    limit: 1e15
  }
];
    
// Format Method:
function formatCount(value)
{
  const format = COUNT_FORMATS.find(format => (value < format.limit));

  value = (1000 * value / format.limit);
  value = Math.round(value * 10) / 10; // keep one decimal number, only if needed

  return (value + format.letter);
}

// Test:
const test = [274, 1683, 56512, 523491, 9523489, 5729532709, 9421032489032];
test.forEach(value => console.log(`${ value } >>> ${ formatCount(value) }`));
```

Answer (score 9):

By eliminating the loop in @martin-sznapka solution, you will reduce the execution time by 40%.

```
function formatNum(num,digits) {
    let units = ['k', 'M', 'G', 'T', 'P', 'E', 'Z', 'Y'];
    let floor = Math.floor(Math.abs(num).toString().length / 3);
    let value=+(num / Math.pow(1000, floor))
    return value.toFixed(value > 1?digits:2) + units[floor - 1];

}
```

Speed test (200000 random samples) for different solution from this thread

```
Execution time: formatNum          418  ms
Execution time: kFormatter         438  ms it just use "k" no "M".."T" 
Execution time: beautify           593  ms doesnt support - negatives
Execution time: shortenLargeNumber 682  ms    
Execution time: Intl.NumberFormat  13197ms
```

Answer (score 6):

Further improving @Yash's answer with negative number support:

```
function nFormatter(num) {
    isNegative = false
    if (num < 0) {
        isNegative = true
    }
    num = Math.abs(num)
    if (num >= 1000000000) {
        formattedNumber = (num / 1000000000).toFixed(1).replace(/\.0$/, '') + 'G';
    } else if (num >= 1000000) {
        formattedNumber =  (num / 1000000).toFixed(1).replace(/\.0$/, '') + 'M';
    } else  if (num >= 1000) {
        formattedNumber =  (num / 1000).toFixed(1).replace(/\.0$/, '') + 'K';
    } else {
        formattedNumber = num;
    }   
    if(isNegative) { formattedNumber = '-' + formattedNumber }
    return formattedNumber;
}

nFormatter(-120000)
"-120K"
nFormatter(120000)
"120K"
```

Answer (score 4):

**2020** edition of [Waylon Flinn's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40724354/12496886).

```js
const SI_SYMBOLS = ["", "k", "M", "G", "T", "P", "E"];

const abbreviateNumber = (number, minDigits, maxDigits) => {
    if (number === 0) return number;

    // determines SI symbol
    const tier = Math.floor(Math.log10(Math.abs(number)) / 3);

    // get suffix and determine scale
    const suffix = SI_SYMBOLS[tier];
    const scale = 10 ** (tier * 3);

    // scale the number
    const scaled = number / scale;

    // format number and add suffix
    return scaled.toLocaleString(undefined, {
        minimumFractionDigits: minDigits,
        maximumFractionDigits: maxDigits,
    }) + suffix;
};
```

Tests and examples:

```js
const abbreviateNumberFactory = (symbols) => (
  (number, minDigits, maxDigits) => {
    if (number === 0) return number;

    // determines SI symbol
    const tier = Math.floor(Math.log10(Math.abs(number)) / 3);

    // get suffix and determine scale
    const suffix = symbols[tier];
    const scale = 10 ** (tier * 3);

    // scale the number
    const scaled = number / scale;

    // format number and add suffix
    return scaled.toLocaleString(undefined, {
      minimumFractionDigits: minDigits,
      maximumFractionDigits: maxDigits,
    }) + suffix;
  }
);

const SI_SYMBOLS = ["", "k", "M", "G", "T", "P", "E"];
const SHORT_SYMBOLS = ["", "K", "M", "B", "T", "Q"];
const LONG_SYMBOLS = ["", " thousand", " million", " billion", " trillion", " quadrillion"];

const abbreviateNumberSI = abbreviateNumberFactory(SI_SYMBOLS);
const abbreviateNumberShort = abbreviateNumberFactory(SHORT_SYMBOLS);
const abbreviateNumberLong = abbreviateNumberFactory(LONG_SYMBOLS);

const tests = [1e5, -9e7, [1009999.999, 2],
  [245345235.34513, 1, 1],
  [-72773144123, 3]
];

const functions = {
  abbreviateNumberSI,
  abbreviateNumberShort,
  abbreviateNumberLong,
};

tests.forEach((test) => {
  const testValue = Array.isArray(test) ? test : [test];
  Object.entries(functions).forEach(([key, func]) => {
    console.log(`${key}(${testValue.join(', ')}) = ${func(...testValue)}`);
  });
});
```

Comment: Welcome to SO.  Your question was flagged for 'Late Answer' review as the question is nearly 9 years old and has 32 other answers.  Whilst your answer may provide some value, very late answers will often be downvoted.

Comment: @GoodJuJu I don't see a reason why would someone "downvote" late answers. There's a lot of users who still answers late, even a user who has 78k reputation. Tell that to that guy.

Answer (score 3):

This post is quite old but I somehow reached to this post searching for something. SO to add my input Numeral js is the one stop solution now a days. It gives a large number of methods to help formatting the numbers

http://numeraljs.com/

Comment: numeraljs is not maintained anymore. The most active fork seems to be [numbro](https://github.com/foretagsplatsen/numbro). But neither of them support the SI/metric notation

Answer (score 3):

Not satisfied any of the posted solutions, so here's my version:

1. Supports positive and negative numbers
2. Supports negative exponents
3. Rounds up to next exponent if possible
4. Performs bounds checking (doesn't error out for very large/small numbers)
5. Strips off trailing zeros/spaces
6. Supports a precision parameter

   ```js
   function abbreviateNumber(number,digits=2) {
     var expK = Math.floor(Math.log10(Math.abs(number)) / 3);
     var scaled = number / Math.pow(1000, expK);

     if(Math.abs(scaled.toFixed(digits))>=1000) { // Check for rounding to next exponent
       scaled /= 1000;
       expK += 1;
     }

     var SI_SYMBOLS = "apμm kMGTPE";
     var BASE0_OFFSET = SI_SYMBOLS.indexOf(' ');

     if (expK + BASE0_OFFSET>=SI_SYMBOLS.length) { // Bound check
       expK = SI_SYMBOLS.length-1 - BASE0_OFFSET;
       scaled = number / Math.pow(1000, expK);
     }
     else if (expK + BASE0_OFFSET < 0) return 0;  // Too small

     return scaled.toFixed(digits).replace(/(\.|(\..*?))0+$/,'$2') + SI_SYMBOLS[expK+BASE0_OFFSET].trim();
   }

   //////////////////

   const tests = [
     [0.0000000000001,2],
     [0.00000000001,2],
     [0.000000001,2],
     [0.000001,2],
     [0.001,2],
     [0.0016,2],
     [-0.0016,2],
     [0.01,2],
     [1,2],
     [999.99,2],
     [999.99,1],
     [-999.99,1],
     [999999,2],
     [999999999999,2],
     [999999999999999999,2],
     [99999999999999999999,2],
   ];

   for (var i = 0; i < tests.length; i++) {
     console.log(abbreviateNumber(tests[i][0], tests[i][1]) );
   }
   ```

Answer (score 3):

```
function   transform(value,args) {
    const suffixes = ['K', 'M', 'B', 'T', 'P', 'E'];

    if (!value) {
      return null;
    }

    if (Number.isNaN(value)) {
      return null;
    }

    if (value < 1000) {
      return value;
    }

    const exp = Math.floor(Math.log(value) / Math.log(1000));

    const returnValue = (value / Math.pow(1000, exp)).toFixed(args) + suffixes[exp - 1];

    return returnValue;
  }
```

transform(9999,2)

// "10.00K"

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the problem, it doesn't explain why or how it answers the question. Please [include an explanation for your code](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762/269535), as that really helps to improve the quality of your post.  Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Answer (score 2):

Further improving Salman's Answer because of the cases like nFormatter(999999,1) that returns 1000K.

```
function formatNumberWithMetricPrefix(num, digits = 1) {
  const si = [
    {value: 1e18, symbol: 'E'},
    {value: 1e15, symbol: 'P'},
    {value: 1e12, symbol: 'T'},
    {value: 1e9, symbol: 'G'},
    {value: 1e6, symbol: 'M'},
    {value: 1e3, symbol: 'k'},
    {value: 0, symbol: ''},
  ];
  const rx = /\.0+$|(\.[0-9]*[1-9])0+$/;
  function divideNum(divider) {
    return (num / (divider || 1)).toFixed(digits);
  }

  let i = si.findIndex(({value}) => num >= value);
  if (+divideNum(si[i].value) >= 1e3 && si[i - 1]) {
    i -= 1;
  }
  const {value, symbol} = si[i];
  return divideNum(value).replace(rx, '$1') + symbol;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is an option using `for`:

```js
function numberFormat(d) {
   for (var e = 0; d >= 1000; e++) {
      d /= 1000;
   }
   return d.toFixed(3) + ['', ' k', ' M', ' G'][e];
}

let s = numberFormat(9012345678);
console.log(s == '9.012 G');
```

Answer (score 1):

Adding on the top answer, this will give 1k for 1000 instead of 1.0k

```
function kFormatter(num) {
    return num > 999 ? num % 1000 === 0 ? (num/1000).toFixed(0) + 'k' : (num/1000).toFixed(1) + 'k' : num
}
```

Answer (score 1):

- Support negative number
- Checking for `!isFinite`
- Change `' K M G T P E Z Y'` to `' K M'` if you want the max unit is `M`
- Option for base ( 1K = 1000 / 1K = 1024 )

---

```js
Number.prototype.prefix = function (precision, base) {

  var units = ' K M G T P E Z Y'.split(' ');

  if (typeof precision === 'undefined') {
    precision = 2;
  }

  if (typeof base === 'undefined') {
    base = 1000;
  }

  if (this == 0 || !isFinite(this)) {
    return this.toFixed(precision) + units[0];
  }

  var power = Math.floor(Math.log(Math.abs(this)) / Math.log(base));
  // Make sure not larger than max prefix
  power = Math.min(power, units.length - 1);

  return (this / Math.pow(base, power)).toFixed(precision) + units[power];
};

console.log('0 = ' + (0).prefix()) // 0.00
console.log('10000 = ' + (10000).prefix()) // 10.00K
console.log('1234000 = ' + (1234000).prefix(1)) // 1.2M
console.log('-10000 = ' + (-10240).prefix(1, 1024)) // -10.0K
console.log('-Infinity = ' + (-Infinity).prefix()) // -Infinity
console.log('NaN = ' + (NaN).prefix()) // NaN
```

Comment: (11000).prefix() equals to 10.74K not very accurate should say 11.00K

Comment: @bmaggi Just change the 1024 to 1000

Answer (score 1):

A modified version of Waylon Flinn's answer with support for negative exponents:

```js
function metric(number) {

  const SI_SYMBOL = [
    ["", "k", "M", "G", "T", "P", "E"], // +
    ["", "m", "μ", "n", "p", "f", "a"] // -
  ];

  const tier = Math.floor(Math.log10(Math.abs(number)) / 3) | 0;

  const n = tier < 0 ? 1 : 0;

  const t = Math.abs(tier);

  const scale = Math.pow(10, tier * 3);

  return {
    number: number,
    symbol: SI_SYMBOL[n][t],
    scale: scale,
    scaled: number / scale
  }
}

function metric_suffix(number, precision) {
  const m = metric(number);
  return (typeof precision === 'number' ? m.scaled.toFixed(precision) : m.scaled) + m.symbol;
}

for (var i = 1e-6, s = 1; i < 1e7; i *= 10, s *= -1) {
  // toggles sign in each iteration
  console.log(metric_suffix(s * (i + i / 5), 1));
}

console.log(metric(0));
```

Expected output:

```
   1.2μ
 -12.0μ
 120.0μ
  -1.2m
  12.0m
-120.0m
   1.2
 -12.0
 120.0
  -1.2k
  12.0k
-120.0k
   1.2M
{ number: 0, symbol: '', scale: 1, scaled: 0 }
```

Answer (score 1):

This function could transform huge numbers (both positive & negative) into a reader friendly format without losing its precision:

```js
function abbrNum(n) {
    if (!n || (n && typeof n !== 'number')) {
      return '';
    }

    const ranges = [
      { divider: 1e12 , suffix: 't' },
      { divider: 1e9 , suffix: 'b' },
      { divider: 1e6 , suffix: 'm' },
      { divider: 1e3 , suffix: 'k' }
    ];
    const range = ranges.find(r => Math.abs(n) >= r.divider);
    if (range) {
      return (n / range.divider).toString() + range.suffix;
    }
    return n.toString();
}

/* test cases */
let testAry = [99, 1200, -150000, 9000000];
let resultAry = testAry.map(abbrNum);
console.log("result array: " + resultAry);
```

Answer (score 1):

Improving @tfmontague's answer further to format decimal places. 33.0k to 33k

```
largeNumberFormatter(value: number): any {
   let result: any = value;

   if (value >= 1e3 && value < 1e6) { result = (value / 1e3).toFixed(1).replace(/\.0$/, '') + 'K'; }
   if (value >= 1e6 && value < 1e9) { result = (value / 1e6).toFixed(1).replace(/\.0$/, '') + 'M'; }
   if (value >= 1e9) { result = (value / 1e9).toFixed(1).replace(/\.0$/, '') + 'T'; }

   return result;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I came up with a very code golfed one, and it is very short!

```js
var beautify=n=>((Math.log10(n)/3|0)==0)?n:Number((n/Math.pow(10,(Math.log10(n)/3|0)*3)).toFixed(1))+["","K","M","B","T",][Math.log10(n)/3|0];

console.log(beautify(1000))
console.log(beautify(10000000))
```

Answer (score 1):

Supports up to `Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER` and down to `Number.MIN_SAFE_INTEGER`

```js
function abbreviateThousands(value) {
  const num = Number(value)
  const absNum = Math.abs(num)
  const sign = Math.sign(num)
  const numLength = Math.round(absNum).toString().length
  const symbol = ['K', 'M', 'B', 'T', 'Q']
  const symbolIndex = Math.floor((numLength - 1) / 3) - 1
  const abbrv = symbol[symbolIndex] || symbol[symbol.length - 1]
  let divisor = 0
  if (numLength > 15) divisor = 1e15
  else if (numLength > 12) divisor = 1e12
  else if (numLength > 9) divisor = 1e9
  else if (numLength > 6) divisor = 1e6
  else if (numLength > 3) divisor = 1e3
  else return num
  return `${((sign * absNum) / divisor).toFixed(divisor && 1)}${abbrv}`
}

console.log(abbreviateThousands(234523452345)) // 234.5b (billion)
console.log(abbreviateThousands(Number.MIN_SAFE_INTEGER)) // -9.0q (quadrillion)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
/*including negative values*/    
function nFormatter(num) {
      let neg = false;
       if(num < 0){
         num = num * -1;
         neg = true;
       }
       if (num >= 1000000000) {
         if(neg){
           return -1 * (num / 1000000000).toFixed(1).replace(/\.0$/, '') + 'G';  
         }
         return (num / 1000000000).toFixed(1).replace(/\.0$/, '') + 'G';
       }
       if (num >= 1000000) {
         if(neg){
           return -1 * (num / 1000000).toFixed(1).replace(/\.0$/, '') + 'M';  
         }
         return (num / 1000000).toFixed(1).replace(/\.0$/, '') + 'M';
       }
       if (num >= 1000) {
         if(neg){
           return -1 * (num / 1000).toFixed(1).replace(/\.0$/, '') + 'K';  
         }
         return (num / 1000).toFixed(1).replace(/\.0$/, '') + 'K';
       }
       return num;
    }
```

Comment: pls add some explanation of your solution

Answer (score 0):

I am using this function. It works for both `php` and `javascript`.

```
    /**
     * @param $n
     * @return string
     * Use to convert large positive numbers in to short form like 1K+, 100K+, 199K+, 1M+, 10M+, 1B+ etc
     */
 function num_format($n) {
        $n_format = null;
        $suffix = null;
        if ($n > 0 && $n < 1000) {
           $n_format = Math.floor($n);   
            $suffix = '';
        }
        else if ($n == 1000) {
            $n_format = Math.floor($n / 1000);   //For PHP only use floor function insted of Math.floor()
            $suffix = 'K';
        }
        else if ($n > 1000 && $n < 1000000) {
            $n_format = Math.floor($n / 1000);
            $suffix = 'K+';
        } else if ($n == 1000000) {
            $n_format = Math.floor($n / 1000000);
            $suffix = 'M';
        } else if ($n > 1000000 && $n < 1000000000) {
            $n_format = Math.floor($n / 1000000);
            $suffix = 'M+';
        } else if ($n == 1000000000) {
            $n_format = Math.floor($n / 1000000000);
            $suffix = 'B';
        } else if ($n > 1000000000 && $n < 1000000000000) {
            $n_format = Math.floor($n / 1000000000);
            $suffix = 'B+';
        } else if ($n == 1000000000000) {
            $n_format = Math.floor($n / 1000000000000);
            $suffix = 'T';
        } else if ($n >= 1000000000000) {
            $n_format = Math.floor($n / 1000000000000);
            $suffix = 'T+';
        }


       /***** For PHP  ******/
       //  return !empty($n_format . $suffix) ? $n_format . $suffix : 0;

       /***** For Javascript ******/
        return ($n_format + $suffix).length > 0 ? $n_format + $suffix : 0;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I decided to expand a lot on @Novellizator's answer here to meet my needs.  I wanted a flexible function to handle most of my formatting needs without external libraries.

### Features

- Option to use order suffixes (k, M, etc.)

  - Option to specify a custom list of order suffixes to use
  - Option to constrain the min and max order
- Control over the number of decimal places
- Automatic order-separating commas
- Optional percent or dollar formatting
- Control over what to return in the case of non-numeric input
- Works on negative and infinite numbers

### Examples

```
let x = 1234567.8;
formatNumber(x);  // '1,234,568'
formatNumber(x, {useOrderSuffix: true});  // '1M'
formatNumber(x, {useOrderSuffix: true, decimals: 3, maxOrder: 1});  // '1,234.568k'
formatNumber(x, {decimals: 2, style: '$'});  // '$1,234,567.80'

x = 10.615;
formatNumber(x, {style: '%'});  // '1,062%'
formatNumber(x, {useOrderSuffix: true, decimals: 1, style: '%'});  // '1.1k%'
formatNumber(x, {useOrderSuffix: true, decimals: 5, style: '%', minOrder: 2});  // '0.00106M%'

formatNumber(-Infinity);  // '-∞'
formatNumber(NaN);  // ''
formatNumber(NaN, {valueIfNaN: NaN});  // NaN
```

### Function

```
/*
 * Return the given number as a formatted string.  The default format is a plain
 * integer with thousands-separator commas.  The optional parameters facilitate
 * other formats:
 *   - decimals = the number of decimals places to round to and show
 *   - valueIfNaN = the value to show for non-numeric input
 *   - style
 *     - '%': multiplies by 100 and appends a percent symbol
 *     - '$': prepends a dollar sign
 *   - useOrderSuffix = whether to use suffixes like k for 1,000, etc.
 *   - orderSuffixes = the list of suffixes to use
 *   - minOrder and maxOrder allow the order to be constrained.  Examples:
 *     - minOrder = 1 means the k suffix should be used for numbers < 1,000
 *     - maxOrder = 1 means the k suffix should be used for numbers >= 1,000,000
 */
function formatNumber(number, {
    decimals = 0,
    valueIfNaN = '',
    style = '',
    useOrderSuffix = false,
    orderSuffixes = ['', 'k', 'M', 'B', 'T'],
    minOrder = 0,
    maxOrder = Infinity
  } = {}) {

  let x = parseFloat(number);

  if (isNaN(x))
    return valueIfNaN;

  if (style === '%')
    x *= 100.0;

  let order;
  if (!isFinite(x) || !useOrderSuffix)
    order = 0;
  else if (minOrder === maxOrder)
    order = minOrder;
  else {
    const unboundedOrder = Math.floor(Math.log10(Math.abs(x)) / 3);
    order = Math.max(
      0,
      minOrder,
      Math.min(unboundedOrder, maxOrder, orderSuffixes.length - 1)
    );
  }

  const orderSuffix = orderSuffixes[order];
  if (order !== 0)
    x /= Math.pow(10, order * 3);

  return (style === '$' ? '$' : '') +
    x.toLocaleString(
      'en-US',
      {
        style: 'decimal',
        minimumFractionDigits: decimals,
        maximumFractionDigits: decimals
      }
    ) +
    orderSuffix +
    (style === '%' ? '%' : '');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Wow there are so many answers on here. I thought I would give you how I solved it as it seemed to be the easiest to read, handles negative numbers, and goes out far in the kilo number range for JavaScript. It also would be easy to change to what you want or extended even farther.

```js
const symbols = [
  { value: 1, symbol: '' },
  { value: 1e3, symbol: 'k' },
  { value: 1e6, symbol: 'M' },
  { value: 1e9, symbol: 'G' },
  { value: 1e12, symbol: 'T' },
  { value: 1e15, symbol: 'P' },
  { value: 1e18, symbol: 'E' }
];

function numberFormatter(num, digits) {
  const numToCheck = Math.abs(num);
  for (let i = symbols.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    if (numToCheck >= symbols[i].value) {
      const newNumber = (num / symbols[i].value).toFixed(digits);
      return `${newNumber}${symbols[i].symbol}`;
    }
  }
  return '0';
}

const tests = [
  { num: 1234, digits: 1 },
  { num: 100000000, digits: 1 },
  { num: 299792458, digits: 1 },
  { num: 759878, digits: 1 },
  { num: -759878, digits: 0 },
  { num: 123, digits: 1 },
  { num: 123.456, digits: 1 },
  { num: -123.456, digits: 2 },
  { num: 123.456, digits: 4 }
];
for (let i = 0; i < tests.length; i++) {
  console.log(`numberFormatter(${tests[i].num}, ${tests[i].digits})=${numberFormatter(tests[i].num, tests[i].digits)}`);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is my version of Waylon Flinn's answer. This removes the .0 and fixes an undefined when the tier is not exactly an integer.

```
const SI_SYMBOL = ['', 'k', 'M', 'G', 'T', 'P', 'E'];

abbreviateNumber(num) {
    const tier = Math.floor(Math.log10(num) / 3) || 0;
    let result = '' + num;
    // if zero, we don't need a suffix
    if (tier > 0) {
      // get suffix and determine scale
      const suffix = SI_SYMBOL[tier];
      const scale = Math.pow(10, tier * 3);
      // scale the number
      const scaled = num / scale;
      // format number and add suffix
      result = scaled.toFixed(1).replace('.0', '') + suffix;
    }
    return result;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, you can use the simplest way around.

```
$('#attrib-id').val(Number(response.column/1000000).toLocaleString()); // Million
```

You can use for other properties by dividing the value by the number you want like if you want to display "K" in front of a number, you should go for `Number(response.column/1000)`, and the rest of the things accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

The JavaScript Internationalization API (Intl) provides a way to format numbers, dates, and strings according to the language and locale conventions. If you're looking to format numbers in a way that represents millions, billions, etc., in a shortened form, you can use the Intl.NumberFormat object with appropriate options.

For example, to format a number to show it in a shortened form for billions, you might specify the notation as "compact" and the compactDisplay as "short" to use abbreviations like "B" for billion. Here's how you could do it:

```js
// Number to format (e.g., 1,250,000,000 for 1.25 billion)
const number = 1250000000;

// Create an Intl.NumberFormat instance for English (US) locale with compact notation
const formatter = new Intl.NumberFormat('en-US', {
  notation: 'compact',
  compactDisplay: 'short' // Other option is 'long'
});

// Format the number
const formattedNumber = formatter.format(number);

document.getElementById('number').innerHTML = formattedNumber;
```

```html
1250000000 is <span id="number"></span>
```

Answer (score -1):

A shorter alternative :

```js
function nFormatter(num) {
    const format = [
      { value: 1e18, symbol: 'E' },
      { value: 1e15, symbol: 'P' },
      { value: 1e12, symbol: 'T' },
      { value: 1e9, symbol: 'G' },
      { value: 1e6, symbol: 'M' },
      { value: 1e3, symbol: 'k' },
      { value: 1, symbol: '' },
    ];
    const formatIndex = format.findIndex((data) => num >= data.value);
    console.log(formatIndex)
    return (num / format[formatIndex === -1? 6: formatIndex].value).toFixed(2) + format[formatIndex === -1?6: formatIndex].symbol;
  }
```

Answer (score -1):

```
function AmountConveter(amount) {
  return Math.abs(amount) > 999
    ? Math.sign(amount) * (Math.abs(amount) / 1000).toFixed(1) + "k"
    : Math.sign(amount) * Math.abs(amount);
}

console.log(AmountConveter(1200)); // 1.2k
console.log(AmountConveter(-1200)); // -1.2k
console.log(AmountConveter(900)); // 900
console.log(AmountConveter(-900)); // -900
```