# Format a javascript number with a Metric Prefix like 1.5K, 1M, 1G, etc

Tags: javascript, formatting

I want to display numbers using a [Metric Prefix](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SI_prefix) with 3 significant digits like so:

```
1 shows as 1
999 shows as 999
1000 shows as 1K
999000 shows as 999K
1000000 shows as 1M
1500000 shows as 1.5M
1000000000 shows as 1G
etc...
```

I could write my own javascript function to do this but I was wondering if there is a standard way of formatting numbers like this?

Comment: @Juhana thanks, that's exactly what I was looking for, not sure why I didn't see it - voted to close my question.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

You can put the ranges in an array of objects, and just loop through it to format the number:

```
var ranges = [
  { divider: 1e18 , suffix: 'E' },
  { divider: 1e15 , suffix: 'P' },
  { divider: 1e12 , suffix: 'T' },
  { divider: 1e9 , suffix: 'G' },
  { divider: 1e6 , suffix: 'M' },
  { divider: 1e3 , suffix: 'k' }
];

function formatNumber(n) {
  for (var i = 0; i < ranges.length; i++) {
    if (n >= ranges[i].divider) {
      return (n / ranges[i].divider).toString() + ranges[i].suffix;
    }
  }
  return n.toString();
}
```

Usage example:

```
var s = formatNumber(999000);
```

To also handle negative numbers, you would add this first in the function:

```
  if (n < 0) {
    return '-' + formatNumber(-n);
  }
```

Comment: That's a neat idea, thanks - I need to tweak it a bit though to get a max of 3 significant figures to show.  I changed your toString() to a toFixed() call which almost does it, but 999999 shows as 1000k rather than 1M.

Comment: @magritte: Well, it rather should, as 999999 is not quite 1000000, so it's 999.999 k.

Comment: Another option for negative numbers is `if (Math.abs(n) >= ranges[i].divider)`.

Comment: You mixed 'P' and 'E' (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metric_prefix). I updated it.