# Formatting very large numbers to local settings in javascript

Tags: javascript, locale, bigdecimal

I saw the question here [How can I format big numbers with toLocaleString?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37799955/how-can-i-format-big-numbers-with-tolocalestring) but this doesn't exactly answer the questino I have.

I'm using the library provided by https://github.com/royNiladri/js-big-decimal which allows for very large number calculations (not just integers). The main issue I have is that there is no way to use ".toLocaleString()". There are "ways" around this (for example, using numeral), but in all the solutions I can find, you have to specify the locales yourself.

Is there any library that will automatically take a string (which is a number) and format it to fit the automatically generated locale of the user?

Example:

```
import bigDecimal from "js-big-decimal";

var x = new bigDecimal('1.0e148')
var y = x.divide(new bigDecimal('3'))
console.log(y.toLocaleString())
```

should print out the appropriate string.

Comment: Explain "but in all the solutions I can find, you have to specify the locales yourself."?

Comment: As an example, numeral makes you add your own locales: http://numeraljs.com/#locales

Answer (score 0):

So, simply, to achieve this, you need to get the number first as a string :

```js
const n = new bigDecimal('1.0e148')
const number = n.divide(new BigDecimal('3')
const string = number.toString() // You can look for it in the documentation, toString() is available
```

Now, we need to get the part of string that is after the point :

```js
const afterPointString = string.slice(string.indexOf("."))
```

and now, we need to define how many digits you need after the point :

```js
const numbersAfterDecimal = 5 // For example, put any number
const resultNumberAfterDecimal = Math.floor(Int(afterPointString)/Math.pow(10, numbersAfterDecimal))*Math.pow(10, numbersAfterDecimal)

const result = new BigDecimal(string.slice(0, string.indexOf(".")+1) + String(resultNumberAfterDecimal))
```

this code is not tested, so please test it and tell me what happens with you

Comment: This doesn't do what I'm asking. I'm asking for it to format the text in the users local settings. So for example in US it would give (1,000,000) in France it would give (1.000.000) in India it would give (10 00 000), etc. But with the number (1.0e148 / 3) which is not possible to do with Integer, and not with bigDecimal either.

Comment: tell me, for example, how do you want to format this number : `1.78475457868689964`

Comment: I want to format it depending on whatever the locale of the user is.

Comment: Then try to convert it to number and use the toLocaleString function : `Number(bigDecimalNum.toString()).toLocaleString()`

Comment: You can't because the numbers are too big and Number can't handle them. Hence why I have to use BigDecimal.  In some cases Number can only handle numbers up to 1.7976931348623157e308. So if I try and do something with 1.0e7812 for example, Number would not work. Hence my question.