# Simplifying big numbers using engineering numbers

Tags: javascript

I am making a project, where im gonna have 6 different numbers, but i want all of them simplified. The problem is when i simplify numbers it takes about 100 lines. So making it 6 times, will give me 600 lines of code just for that.

```
if (money >= 1000 && money <= 999999){
    moneyshow = money/1000;
    document.getElementById("money").innerHTML = "Money: "+moneyshow.toFixed(2)+" k $";
  }
  if (money >= 1000000 && money <= 999999999){
    moneyshow = money/1000000;
    document.getElementById("money").innerHTML = "Money: "+moneyshow.toFixed(2)+" m $";
  }
  if (money >= 1000000000 && money <= 999999999999){
    moneyshow = money/1000000000;
    document.getElementById("money").innerHTML = "Money: "+moneyshow.toFixed(2)+" b $";
  }
  if (money >= 1000000000000 && money <= 999999999999999){
    moneyshow = money/1000000000000;
    document.getElementById("money").innerHTML = "Money: "+moneyshow.toFixed(2)+" t $";
  }
  if (money >= 1000000000000000 && money <= 999999999999999999){
    moneyshow = money/1000000000000000;
    document.getElementById("money").innerHTML = "Money: "+moneyshow.toFixed(2)+" quad $";
  }
  if (money >= 1000000000000000000 && money <= 999999999999999999999){
    moneyshow = money/1000000000000000000;
    document.getElementById("money").innerHTML = "Money: "+moneyshow.toFixed(2)+" quint $";
  }
  if (money >= 0 && money <= 999 || money >= 1000000000000000000000) {
    moneyshow = money;
    document.getElementById("money").innerHTML = "Money: "+moneyshow.toFixed(2)+"$";
  }
```

Is there any way i could simplify that ? Also im gonna need it so i can use it on 6 or more numbers at once.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to format a number as 2.5K if a thousand or more, otherwise 900 in javascript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9461621/how-to-format-a-number-as-2-5k-if-a-thousand-or-more-otherwise-900-in-javascrip)

Comment: Turn it into a function so it is reusable. Don't directly alter the HTML of the page, make the function return the number with suffix and then work with that outside of the function

Comment: You mean, function(number) and inside function, return ? I dont know how return works. Can I do var number = function(number) ?

Answer (score 0):

Declare 2 variables, inside each if , set these variables to the number you want to divide by and the string you want to append.

```
var divideBy;
var appendStr;

if (money >= 1000 && money <= 999999)
{
    divideBy = 1000;
    appendStr = "k $";
}
```

Then at least you can do this just once:

```
moneyshow = money/ divideBy;
document.getElementById("money").innerHTML = "Money: "+moneyshow.toFixed(2)+ appendStr;
```

The beauty of variables in Javascript is that they are not strongly typed.

Comment: I dont understand, is yourvariable1 a string or float ?