# How to display 1000 000 as 1Million

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

How can i implement 'k' or 'm' prefixer to my code? I am not sure how to add it to my code.

i want the number 1000 to display as 1k how can i make the prefixer in my code. can someone please help me add it to my code please.

Comment: This might help you https://jsfiddle.net/lesson8/5tt7d3e6/

Comment: Thanks I will try it out - anything that easier to read though?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
if (number >= 1000000) {
    document.write((number / 1000000).toFixed(2) + "M")
}
else if (number >= 1000) {
    document.write((number / 1000).toFixed(2) + "K");
}
else {
    document.write(number)
}
```

Comment: much better - this also allows me to better adjust what wording to display - thanks

Answer (score 3):

To use a thousands separator, you can use the `Intl.NumberFormat` method. For instance Sweden uses the space as thousands separator, so you could reference that:

```js
console.log(new Intl.NumberFormat('se').format(1000000));
```

For a way to format a number with K or M suffixes, see [this complete answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9462382/5459839).

Comment: thank you this is a good idea and i will see where i can implement this idea

Comment: your code was easiest to apply and still looks good in my code

Comment: Good to hear it was useful to you.

Comment: I am sorry to see you removed the acceptance of this answer 1 year later. Was there an issue with it?