# Convert long number in to 1M, 1K etc in Javascript

Tags: javascript

How can I stop loop when the first time if condition is true?

```
<p id="numb"></p>
```

And here is my code javascript, Where i did mistake? i want that when the condition is true the loop stops and don't check other variants?

```
function round (number) {
    var str = number.replace(/[, .]/g, "");
    var numb = parseInt(str);
    var point = {
        "T": Math.pow(10, 12),
        "B": Math.pow(10, 9),
        "M": Math.pow(10, 6),
        "K": Math.pow(10, 3)
    };

    Object.keys(point).forEach(function (key) {
        var pNumb = point[key];
       // console.log(pNumb);
      //  console.log(key);
        if (pNumb < numb) {
            var letter  = key;
            console.log(letter);
            var z = numb / pNumb;
            if (numb % pNumb !== 0) {
                document.getElementById("numb").innerHTML = z.toFixed(1) + letter;
            } else {
                document.getElementById("numb").innerHTML = z + letter;
            }
            return false;
        }

    });
}
    round("665,421,000")
```

Comment: [Related answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40724354) that doesn’t use loops.

Answer (score 1):

Returning `false` will not stop a `forEach` loop early. The only way to stop such a loop early is to throw an exception (which you need to catch outside the loop).

I normally recommend [using a `for`...`of` loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3010840/loop-through-an-array-in-javascript/10167931#10167931) instead of `forEach`, if you are using a new enough version of Javascript. But in this case, since you're calling `forEach` on the result of calling `Object.keys()` on the object (instead of the object itself), you can just use a `for`...`in` loop, which has been in Javascript forever.

Comment: Ok i understand thanks, but i fixed it with for in loop is it wrong way?

Comment: Since you were iterating over the `keys` of the object, `for`...`in` is actually correct. If you were just calling `forEach` on the object itself, the replacement would be `for`...`of`.

Answer (score 0):

Besides `forEach` not returning a value if you return from it, your code is wrong, because you're assuming object keys maintain their order, you should write something like this instead:

```
function round (number) {
    const str = number.replace(/[, .]/g, "");
    const numb = parseInt(str);
    const point = [
        ["T", Math.pow(10, 12)],
        ["G", Math.pow(10, 9)],
        ["M", Math.pow(10, 6)],
        ["K", Math.pow(10, 3)]
    ];

    for (const [key, pNumb] of point) {
        if (pNumb < numb) {
            const letter  = key;
            const z = numb / pNumb;
            if (numb % pNumb !== 0) {
                return z.toFixed(1) + letter;
            } else {
                return z + letter;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

You also have a typo, instead of `"G"`, you have `"B"`.

Comment: K, M, G, T are SI prefixes for those numbers.