# Add units to counter dynamically (K, L, M)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm working on the counter using jquery. Now I'm trying to add units like K, L, M I got a script but how to implement in my code I unable to find out.
My initial code:

```js
$('.count').each(function() {
  $(this).prop('Counter', 0).animate({
    Counter: $(this).text()
  }, {
    duration: 4000,
    easing: 'swing',
    step: function(num) {
      $(this).text(Math.ceil(num));
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div><span class="count">2000</span></div>
<div><span class="count">1000</span></div>
```

This the link I found on the StackOverflow I want to implement in my code 
[Found link on stack](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14994860/7978664) and I had tried like this

```js
$('.count').each(function() {
  $(this).prop('Counter', 0).animate({
    Counter: $(this).text()
  }, {
    duration: 4000,
    easing: 'swing',
    step: function(num) {
      $(this).text(Math.ceil(num));
      if (num >= 1000000000) {
        //$(this).text(Math.ceil(num));
        return (num / 1000000000).toFixed(1).replace(/\.0$/, '') + 'G';
      }
      if (num >= 1000000) {
        //$(this).text(Math.ceil(num));
        return (num / 1000000).toFixed(1).replace(/\.0$/, '') + 'M';
      }
      if (num >= 100000) {
        //$(this).text(Math.ceil(num));
        return (num / 100000).toFixed(1).replace(/\.0$/, '') + 'L';
      }
      if (num >= 1000) {
        //$(this).text(Math.ceil(num));
        return (num / 1000).toFixed(1).replace(/\.0$/, '') + 'K';
      }
      return num;
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div><span class="count">2000</span></div>
<div><span class="count">1000</span></div>
```

Here counter is working fine but units are not added Can anyone suggest how to append these units.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's becouse you do the calculations **after** you update the text with this line `$(this).text(Math.ceil(num));`

Also it seems like the code you got from stackoverflow should be in a function

```js
$('.count').each(function() {
  function formatNum(num){
    if (num >= 1000000000) {
      //$(this).text(Math.ceil(num));
      return (num / 1000000000).toFixed(1).replace(/\.0$/, '') + 'G';
    }
    if (num >= 1000000) {
      //$(this).text(Math.ceil(num));
      return (num / 1000000).toFixed(1).replace(/\.0$/, '') + 'M';
    }
    if (num >= 100000) {
      //$(this).text(Math.ceil(num));
      return (num / 100000).toFixed(1).replace(/\.0$/, '') + 'L';
    }
    if (num >= 1000) {
      //$(this).text(Math.ceil(num));
      return (num / 1000).toFixed(1).replace(/\.0$/, '') + 'K';
    }
    return num;
  }
  $(this).prop('Counter', 0).animate({
    Counter: $(this).text()
  }, {
    duration: 4000,
    easing: 'swing',
    step: function(num) {
      $(this).text(formatNum(Math.ceil(num)));
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div><span class="count">2000</span></div>
<div><span class="count">1000</span></div>
```

Answer (score 3):

It's because you update view first (`$(this).text(Math.ceil(num));`) and only then do calculations. Check my update:

```js
$('.count').each(function() {
  $(this).prop('Counter', 0).animate({
    Counter: $(this).text()
  }, {
    duration: 4000,
    easing: 'swing',
    step: function(num) {
      var unit = Math.ceil(num);

      if (num >= 1000000000) {
        //$(this).text(Math.ceil(num));
        unit = (num / 1000000000).toFixed(1).replace(/\.0$/, '') + 'G';
      } else if (num >= 1000000) {
        //$(this).text(Math.ceil(num));
        unit = (num / 1000000).toFixed(1).replace(/\.0$/, '') + 'M';
      } else if (num >= 100000) {
        //$(this).text(Math.ceil(num));
        unit = (num / 100000).toFixed(1).replace(/\.0$/, '') + 'L';
      } else if (num >= 1000) {
        //$(this).text(Math.ceil(num));
        unit = (num / 1000).toFixed(1).replace(/\.0$/, '') + 'K';
      }

      $(this).text(unit);
      return num;
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div><span class="count">5000000000</span></div>
<div><span class="count">2000</span></div>
<div><span class="count">1000</span></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
$('.count').each(function() {
  $(this).prop('Counter', 0).animate({
    Counter: $(this).text()
  }, {
    duration: 4000,
    easing: 'swing',
    step: function(num) {
      //$(this).text(Math.ceil(num));
      if (num >= 1000000000) {
         $(this).text((num / 1000000000).toFixed(1).replace(/\.0$/, '') + 'G');       
        return (num / 1000000000).toFixed(1).replace(/\.0$/, '') + 'G';
      }
      if (num >= 1000000) {
         $(this).text((num / 1000000).toFixed(1).replace(/\.0$/, '') + 'M');
        return (num / 1000000).toFixed(1).replace(/\.0$/, '') + 'M';
      }
      if (num >= 100000) {
         $(this).text((num / 100000).toFixed(1).replace(/\.0$/, '') + 'L');
        return (num / 100000).toFixed(1).replace(/\.0$/, '') + 'L';
      }
      if (num >= 1000) {
        $(this).text((num / 1000).toFixed(1).replace(/\.0$/, '') + 'K');
        return (num / 1000).toFixed(1).replace(/\.0$/, '') + 'K';
      }
      $(this).text(Math.ceil(num));
      return num;
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div><span class="count">2000</span></div>
<div><span class="count">1000</span></div>
```

Comment: crap, I'm too slow to write