# How to format numbers in thousands, million or billions in vue.js?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

like this:   12000 = 12k , 1000000 = 1m , 1430 = 1.4k ,

```
 <div v-for="item in items" :key:"item">
   <span>{{item.num}}</span>
</div>

<script lang='ts'>

  items:any[]=[
     {num:"122256879"},
     {num:"12000000"},
     {num:"1430"},
  ]

</script>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Format a number as 2.5K if a thousand or more, otherwise 900](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9461621/format-a-number-as-2-5k-if-a-thousand-or-more-otherwise-900)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found two `npm` packages that seem to do the trick:

https://www.npmjs.com/package/number-shortener

This first one doesn't seem very widely used, but looking at the code it's very lightweight.

The second is:

https://www.npmjs.com/package/number-abbreviate

More popular and also very lightweight. I guess read and play around to see which one suits you better.

Answer (score -1):

Create a filter (inside main.js)

```
Vue.filter('formatNumber', (value) => {
  ending=['k','m','b','t']
  if(n.length<4){
    return n;
  }else{
    return `${n[0]}${n[1]!='0'?`.${n[1]}`:''}${ending[Math.floor((n.length-1)/3)-1]}`;
  }
})
```

for numbers greater than or equal 1000 (length of 4) you return the first digit `n[0]` and then if the next digit `n[1]` isn't 0 include that with a `.`. The ending/postfix is based on the original length.

and then from your code

```
<div v-for="item in items" :key:"item">
   <span>{{item.num | formatNumber}}</span>
</div>
```