# Display follower count in a shortened version

Tags: javascript

So basically I would like to have 1.9M instead of 1 900 000 to show follower counts.
or 1.9K instead of 1900, or 22.3K instead of 22300, and so on...

How can I do this with javascript?

Comment: Dividing by a thousand or a million and adding a K or an M

Comment: wow, that's quite simple... Should've thought about it :)) Thanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This answer was taken from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9462382/14502223).

```js
function nFormatter(num, digits) {
  var si = [
    { value: 1, symbol: "" },
    { value: 1E3, symbol: "k" },
    { value: 1E6, symbol: "M" },
    { value: 1E9, symbol: "G" },
    { value: 1E12, symbol: "T" },
    { value: 1E15, symbol: "P" },
    { value: 1E18, symbol: "E" }
  ];
  var rx = /\.0+$|(\.[0-9]*[1-9])0+$/;
  var i;
  for (i = si.length - 1; i > 0; i--) {
    if (num >= si[i].value) {
      break;
    }
  }
  return (num / si[i].value).toFixed(digits).replace(rx, "$1") + si[i].symbol;
}
```