# Format number to multiples of 1000 and round it off to one decimal place

Tags: d3.js, number-formatting, apache-superset

I am have a number like this:

```
988517.05
```

I am trying to display it as:

```
998.5 K
```

which means multiple of thousand rounded off to one decimal place.

What should be the Number Format defined in the customization tab of Apache superset.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Format a number as 2.5K if a thousand or more, otherwise 900](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9461621/format-a-number-as-2-5k-if-a-thousand-or-more-otherwise-900)

Comment: I need to make this configuration at the Superset level, not at conventional programming.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `.4s` for the Number Format:

[image]